# How to convert a SVG into a PDF with a specific resolution?

Tags: xcode, pdf, svg, xcode9

I've seen many questions of how to convert SVGs into a PDF, but never a question that specified the resolution of the PDF.

I got some icons off of material.io/icons to use in my iOS app. I downloaded the SVG version of them, and in order to use them in Xcode, I need a vector PDF with a size of around 25x25 (for use in the tab bar), but I cannot seem to change the resolution in any application I use. Currently, two are stuck at 18x18 and one at 15x15 after a conversion from Inkscape and are too small for use as tab bar icons in the iOS app.

Are there any online tools or programs I can get to do what I want?

Note: I'm developing the app on macOS High Sierra, but I have access to Fedora 28 and Windows 10 as well.

Comment: Have you tried inkscape or similar utilities: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/export-multiple-svg-files-generated-with-inkscape-to-multiple-pdf-files

Comment: I did try Inkscape, with the --export-height and --export-width set to no avail. I'll try out the others there.

Comment: if you look at that page, with inkscape -d x - you can set both height and width using x. It should work, except you are seeing blanks in your image.

Comment: `Inkscape -d` made the image no longer a vector

Comment: image magick can do it from command line.

Comment: image magick either would make it no longer a vector or could not create the correct size

Answer (score 1):

After many failed attempts, it seems the only thing that works as it should in my circumstance was [Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com).

I haven't tried GIMP but I may in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Xcode 12 you can start using SVGs in xcassets file.